# linear decompositions of tensor product vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, tensor-products

I have a vector space $V^{(1)} \otimes V^{(2)}$, a set of vectors $\{s_i\} \in V^{(1)}$ and $\{s_j\} \in V^{(2)}$, that span the respective spaces such that any one vector, e.g. $s_{i'}$, can be written as a linear sum of the other vectors in $\{s_i\}$  (and similar for $s_{j'}\in V^{(2)}$). I want to write one of these vectors, $s_{i'}\otimes s_{j'}$, as a linear sum of the other vectors with non-zero coefficients. I can obviously do this with the sets of vectors $s_{i'}\otimes \{ s_j \}$ or $\{s_i\}\otimes s_{j'}$. What if i want to do it with a set of vectors that arent all the same on one tensor element? I can do this with the total set of vectors $\{ s_i\}\otimes \{s_j\}$, and the linear sum will factorise to be of the form $$s_{i'}\otimes s_{j'}=\sum\limits_{ij}x_{ij}s_{i}\otimes s_{j} $$ is it possible to do this over a set of vectors that 1) not all states in the linear sum are the same on one tensor element, 2) all states in the sum have non-zero coefficients (i.e. they actually are in the sum), and 3) the sum doesnt factorise, e.g. something like $x_1 s_1 \otimes s_1 + x_2 s_1 \otimes s_3 + x_3 s_2 \otimes s_1$

EDIT: Essentially, can i write a decomposable vector as an indecomposable sum of decomposable vectors

Comment: I think the "in" symbol in the first line in the first equation is out of place.

Comment: Are the spaces finite dimensional, e.g. are the sets $\{s_i\}$ and $\{s_j\}$ finite?

Comment: yes, they are finite dimensional